# Can I make Visual Studio automatically show corresponding header or implementation file in vertical split?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to Visual Studio, but have used several other IDE's over the years. I'm stunned by the poor out-of-the-box management of files, filters and "presentation" of coding, and now trying to find if there's a way to customize it the way I've found to be optimal for me.

First off, when programming C++, I'd like for the IDE to use a vertically split automatic view. Dragging and dropping a view to the right side giving me a "static" split is no problem, but that file will stay there untouched until I open another file while in this active view.

What I want is to make it so that when I click a .cpp-file in the explorer, it will show up in the left view - and its corresponding header-file will show in the right view. Likewise, when clicking a header-file, I'd want it to be presented in the right view and the corresponding .cpp-file to show in the left view. If either doesn't exist, just show a blank screen on its side.
When ctrl-clicking a class name, I'd want both the cpp and header-file to be presented, cpp on left and header on right.
Is this not possible?

The second thing that grinds my gears is the solution explorer. I simply don't understand the value of the filter system. I surely do not want every single .cpp file lined up alphabetically under each other, and every single header-file alphabetically another place. I want the explorer to replicate the folder structure as-is. And let me create a file in "src/my_folder/" by right-clicking "my_folder" and add->new item.

I've found that I can click "Switch views" and select "Folder view", but doing this seems to also invalidate the "Solution" and any configurations etc. The solution is literally gone, and the Build/Run-command switches to "Current document" and is completely detached from the project itself.
The closest option I've found is to be in "Solution view" and select "Show all files". The problem is that this shows literally all files and folders, including "output-folders", "hidden" and completely irrelevant files and folders that I don't want here. And I'm naturally not able to "hide" these files, as this is an option to "show all files".

Xcode on Mac has both of these features (and more snacks) pretty flawlessly implemented, and is my all-time favorite IDE per now.
Is there any way to replicate these features in Visual Studio?